# redirect if user is not logged in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, product

I am creating a wordpress site for a client that wants to redirect certain products to login page. I have already had success redirecting entire shop page, etc.. but, I need to redirect only certain products....

This is what I have tried, but it redirects EVERY product to login page:

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() && $product_id = 7854 ) {
    wp_redirect('my-site-url');
}
```

I have also tried :

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() && is_product(7854))  {
    wp_redirect('my-site-url');
    exit;
}
```

and again, it redirects ALL products to login page.

Am I missing something here? Thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where are you taking that var $product_id? The product id is in fact the post->ID; If you are on single post/product, that yould be used. 

Apart from that, is_product - Returns true when viewing a single product. That don´t means that will check the ID if you use it as paramenter, this function don´t have parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you are on the right track with the second snippet.

- You MUST use exit(); after a wp_redirect() call

However, looking at the Woocommerce documentation, [`is_product()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product.html) does not accept any arguments.  This means passing '7854' in `is_product(7854)` is meaningless to the function.  It returns a boolean (true|false) based on whether you are viewing a single product, regardless of which product.

Looking at the documentation for [`is_product_tag()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_product_tag.html) I think that if you substituted `is_product_tag( 'your-product-slug' )` that would work.